# Растянутый экран при полноэкранном режиме в играх

Tags: windows, экран, монитор

В многих играх у меня растянутый экран при полноэкранном режиме, но если включить полноэкранный в окне то все хорошо. Я бы мог так и играть, но это забирает много FPS и не во всех играх есть такой режим. К сожалению я не могу показать скрин, потому-что в скрине картинка выглядит нормально. В настройках Windows у меня стоит 59,934 ГЦ потому-что если поставить другие значения(59,940; 60.000) то уже картинка монитора становится также растянутой. Я и пытался поменять что-то в панель управления NVIDIA, но итак у меня ничего не получилось. Что делать?

P.S Раньше у меня такой проблемы не было, она появилось после переустановки Windows. Также если присмотреться к скринам, то на полноэкранном видны полосы.
Версия Windows 20H2.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте, в настройках игры разрешение соответствовало реальному разрешению экрана.

Comment: сфоткайте со стороны чемто монитор, раз скрины врут.

Comment: Приведите параметры монитора и установленную версию windows и видео драйвера, а также скрин панели Nvidia страницы Изменение разрешения и Регулировка размера и положения рабочего стола.

Comment: Попробуйте на вкладке Регулировка размера и положения рабочего стола включить режим Не выполнять масштабирования.

Comment: User7860670 Не работает

Comment: Млин, оно заразное, у меня только что все нормально работало, а теперь в панели управления 59,997 Гц и мыло при переключении в 60 Гц...